# Search floop works the first pass but not the second

Tags: c++, loops

I made this function to search for a number which the user inputs which is `x`.
The idea is that the user inputs the number of a runner in a marathon and the program outputs the info of the runner that number belongs to.
The loop should also end if the user inputs 0.

The problem is that it either works only the first time and not the second, or it doesn't at all and only displays the info of `runner[0]`.

Here is the code (sorry about the Spanish)

```
void search(race *runner){

    int flag = 1;
    int x;
    while (flag = 1){

        cout << "Porfavor entre el numero del corredor, si desea terminar la busqueda entre el numero 0 "<<endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){

            if (x = runner[i].number)
                cout << "El corredor que usted busca es " <<
                runner[i].name << " con el numero " << runner[i].number<<endl;

            if (x = 0)
                flag = 0;

            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: You have a typo. Instead of `if (x = runner[i].number)`, you need `if (x == runner[i].number)`. You need `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: There are also typo's in `while (flag = 1)` and `if (x = 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious fixes of changing

```
while (flag = 1){
```

to

```
while (flag == 1){
      //    ^^^
```

and changing

```
        if (x = runner[i].number)
```

to

```
        if (x == runner[i].number)
        //    ^^^
```

you can avoid some unnecessary work in our code by moving where you check whether `x` is equal to `0`.

```
// while (flag = 1){
// This is also wrong.

while (flag == 1){

   cout << "Porfavor entre el numero del corredor, si desea terminar la busqueda entre el numero 0 "<<endl;
   cin >> x;
   cout << endl;
   if ( x == 0 )
   {
      flag = 0;
      // No need to go through the loop for this case.
   }
   else
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){

         if (x == runner[i].number)
            cout << "El corredor que usted busca es " <<
               runner[i].name << " con el numero " << runner[i].number<<endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it should work, actually you are confuse with `=` and `==`, first study about how to compare two elements.

```
void search(race *runner){

    int flag = 1;
    int x;
    while (flag == 1){

        cout << "Porfavor entre el numero del corredor, si desea terminar la busqueda entre el numero 0 "<<endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){

            if (x == runner[i].number)
                cout << "El corredor que usted busca es " <<
                runner[i].name << " con el numero " << runner[i].number<<endl;

            if (x == 0)
                flag = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some simple mistakes in your code. You are using `=` instead of `==` in three places in your code, namely

```
while (flag = 1)

if (x = runner[i].number)

if (x = 0)
```

Change these to

```
while (flag == 1)

if (x == runner[i].number)

if (x == 0)
```

What you are doing is, you are assigning them these values instead of checking for equality. This is a common mistake many people make and can become really confusing and sometimes it may cause an infinite loop. You should thus check for errors like these in the beginning.

Hope this solves your problem.